# How to import a data with date format like this into mysql?

Tags: mysql

With Data like this:

```
* id    txns_date   sale
* 1234  01JAN2011   100
* 1235  03FEB2011   101
* 1236  04MAR2011   102
```

I tried the following code, but the txns_date fields are all `NULL`;

```
create table tran(
id int,
txns_date date,
sale dec(10,2)
);


load data local INFILE 'c:/Projects/tran.txt' into table  tran
fields terminated by '\t'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines
(id,@var1,sale)
set txns_date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1,'%d%b%Y')
;
```

Comment: %b ? not $b? The format should be using % rather than $?

Comment: It is a typo, should be %. I have fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If there's really a `*` in front of each row then you have *four* columns? Do the LOAD DATA with no conversion to make sure it's loading what you think.

Comment: No, it only has three columns, ' * ' is used to separate the rows.